# iTunes Store Operation Failed in Xcode 9

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, xcode9, info.plist, appicon

I'am trying to submit my app in iTunes connect and I always have the following error:

[image]

Im using MacOS High Sierra 10.13.3 and Xcode 9.2 (9C40b), I'm using the icon above in my AppIcon:

```
icon-20.png = 20x20
icon-20@2x.png = 40x40
icon-20@3x.png = 60,60
icon-29.png = 29x29
icon-29@2x.png = 58x58
icon-29@3x.png = 87x87
icon-40.png = 40x40
icon-40@2x.png = 80x80
icon-40@3x.png = 120x120
icon-60@2x.png = 120x120
icon-60@3x.png = 180x180
icon-76.png = 76x76
icon-76@2x.png = 152x152
icon-83.5@2x.png = 167x167
icon-1024.png = 1024x1024
```

this is my content.json

```
{
  "images" : [
    {
      "size" : "20x20",
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "filename" : "icon-20@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "20x20",
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "filename" : "icon-20@3x.png",
      "scale" : "3x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "29x29",
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "filename" : "icon-29@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "29x29",
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "filename" : "icon-29@3x.png",
      "scale" : "3x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "40x40",
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "filename" : "icon-40@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "40x40",
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "filename" : "icon-40@3x.png",
      "scale" : "3x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "60x60",
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "filename" : "icon-60@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "60x60",
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "filename" : "icon-60@3x.png",
      "scale" : "3x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "20x20",
      "idiom" : "ipad",
      "filename" : "icon-20.png",
      "scale" : "1x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "20x20",
      "idiom" : "ipad",
      "filename" : "icon-20@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "29x29",
      "idiom" : "ipad",
      "filename" : "icon-29.png",
      "scale" : "1x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "29x29",
      "idiom" : "ipad",
      "filename" : "icon-29@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "40x40",
      "idiom" : "ipad",
      "filename" : "icon-40.png",
      "scale" : "1x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "40x40",
      "idiom" : "ipad",
      "filename" : "icon-40@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "76x76",
      "idiom" : "ipad",
      "filename" : "icon-76.png",
      "scale" : "1x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "76x76",
      "idiom" : "ipad",
      "filename" : "icon-76@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "83.5x83.5",
      "idiom" : "ipad",
      "filename" : "icon-83.5@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "iconxicon",
      "idiom" : "ios-marketing",
      "filename" : "icon-1024.png",
      "scale" : "1x"
    }
  ],
  "info" : {
    "version" : 1,
    "author" : "xcode"
  }
}
```

My app have Deployment target in 10.0 and iosDeployment Target = 10.0
Whats are wrong? deleted my AppIcon folder in assets and create again and this error persist, I was clean project(shift+cmd+k), I was create new archives(+20), nothing solve this problem and I dont know if have a trick or a workarround to solve this. Thanks

Comment: Have you checked that the size of the png is actually 120x120 pixels?

Comment: @RoelKoops its appear cocoapods error, I posted the (workarround) solution

Answer (score 0):

I found some workarround in this [link](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7003) , **this is not the solution** but works for now.

I comment the file Pods-MyApp-resources.sh located in Pods/Targets Support Files/Pods-MyApp like follow image:

[image]

After that I clean project, archive, and upload.